# memory error in my program when I set theano.config.device to gpu

Tags: python, gpu, theano

My graphics system is GT 550M

When I run my program on the gpu It gives following error and I don't know how I fix this problem

```
MemoryError: error freeing device pointer 0x0000000500C60000 (the launch timed out and was terminated)
Apply node that caused the error: GpuReshape{4}(GpuConv{valid, (2, 2), None, (7, 7), True, (3, 224, 224), (7, 7)}.0, TensorConstant{[672   1 109 109]})
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D), TensorType(int64, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(7, 96, 109, 109), (4L,)]
Inputs strides: [(1140576, 11881, 109, 1), (8L,)]
Inputs scalar values: ['not scalar', 'not scalar']

Debugprint of the apply node: 
GpuReshape{4} [@A] <CudaNdarrayType(float32, (False, True, False, False))> ''   
 |GpuConv{valid, (2, 2), None, (7, 7), True, (3, 224, 224), (7, 7)} [@B] <CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D)> ''   
 | |GpuDimShuffle{0,3,1,2} [@C] <CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D)> ''   
 | | |GpuFromHost [@D] <CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D)> ''   
 | |   |x [@E] <TensorType(float32, 4D)>
 | |<CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D)> [@F] <CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D)>
 |TensorConstant{[672   1 109 109]} [@G] <TensorType(int64, vector)>

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-traces when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flags optimizer=fast_compile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error by cuda are returned async. So part of the error message can be unrelated. Here is the first line:

MemoryError: error freeing device pointer 0x0000000500C60000 (the launch timed out and was terminated)

The answer is in the second part: the launch timed out and was terminated

You GPU is attached to a monitor. In that case, there is a limit of 5s for each GPU kernel call. It happen that it got busted and the driver killed that kernel. This is to prevent the screen from being not responsive.

possible solution:
1) use a different gpu for the monitor.
2) make the kernel faster by using small input data (lower batch size for example)
3) buy a faster GPU, not sure it will work and if it work with your current size, the problem will appear with bigger size.